# How to select an element by transform: rotation?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm having trouble writing a selector for a specific element with a certain value for `rotateX()`.

Say I had the following:

```
<figure style="opacity: .5; transform: rotateX(144deg) translateZ(238px);"></figure>    
<figure style="opacity: 1; transform: rotateX(156deg) translateZ(238px);"></figure>
<figure style="opacity: .8; transform: rotateX(168deg) translateZ(238px);"></figure>
```

How would I select the middle one?  `$('[style="opacity: 1; transform: rotateX(84deg) translateZ(238px);"]')` works, but the problem is that I won't actually know the opacity at runtime.

How can I select *only by* the `rotateX` value?  Or is this even possible?

Comment: so I take it figure:nth-child(2) doesn't work?

Comment: No, not an option. Sorry.

Comment: can you not just switch out style with a class and do it that way?

Comment: @Keith: I could, but this is a library and I'd rather not modify it if possible.  Plus, it was cool to learn you could do `style~=`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following selector:

`$('[style~="rotateX(84deg)"]')`

This should select elements who's style contain "rotateX(84deg)"